# C# Conditionally Declare Variables

Tags: c#

I'm trying to declare a variable that is dependent on the bool 'multiline'.

<...some code...>

```
if (multiline)
{
    string[] line;
}
else 
{
    string line;
}
```

<...code that uses 'line'...>

But this *doesn't work* because the declaration of the variables is at the wrong stack level (I think); these variables would only be able to be used within the if/else statements, but I would like to be able to use them outside of the if/else statements.

Is there a way in C# to conditionally create variables?

Comment: can you add concrete use-case please.

Comment: How would you use that variable outside of their declaring scope if you don't know what types they have?

Comment: "**Scope**" is the correct term here, not stack. Now read up on variable scope.

Comment: A single string and an array of string are very different things. In this case, you probably want to always use an array of strings (or an `IEnumerable<string>`),, where in the `else` part it has only one member.

Comment: in a kind of 'dirty' way, you can use object and boxing your variable or use dynamic, but I doubt that it will make your life easier. When guessing your use case and as the other already wrote, a collection type for both branches would be the way to go.

Comment: What is the type of `line` after the end of the else that you want? E.g., how are you going to use `line` later?

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] str;
if (multiline)
{
    string[] line = str;
}
else 
{
    string line = str[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.
However, I do not believe the question is explained well. Please rethink if you wish to declare a variable dynamically or use its value dynamically.

If the later is true, you can use it in below 2 ways.

1. Using dynamic

   ```
   dynamic lines;
   if (multiline)
   {
       lines = new string[10];
   }
   else
   {
       lines = "<some string value>";
   }
   ```
2. Using array of strings.

   ```
   string[] lines;
   if (multiline)
   {
       lines = <<string array values>>
   }
   else
   {
       lines = "<some string value>";
   }

   if(lines.Length == 1)
   {
       // handle single line
   }

   if(lines.Length > 1)
   {
      // handle multi line
   }
   ```

Understand that even if the variables are declared conditionally/dynamically you will have to determine the type at a later point when you wish to handle the variable. My advice would be to bring more details to this question for us to help you better.